# Same `where` clause for multiple tests

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

I know about [data driven testing](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html) with the `where` clause in Spock.
But how can I expand this to use one `where` for multiple tests?

For example, I have I set of tests I want to run against different versions of a library:

```
@Unroll
def "test1 #firstlibVersion, #secondLibVersion"() {...}

@Unroll
def "test2 #firstlibVersion, #secondLibVersion"() {...}
...
```

The where clause might look like this:

```
where:
[firstlibVersion, secondLibVersion] <<
    [['0.1', '0.2'], ['0.2', '0.4']].combinations()
```

I don't want to repeat this same where clause in every test. I could achieve that by reading environment variables in the tests and running the test suite multiple times with different env vars (test matrix style as CI services like travis support it).

But I would prefer to do that directly in the tests so I don't have to run the test suite multiple times. Does Spock support this somehow?

Comment: AFAIK, is not possible in the current version of spock. DataProviders are link to the feature test through 'where' block. You can share DataProviders , but you have to specify at least a where block for each test

Comment: Are there plans to support this in future versions? Any open proposals?

Answer (score 5):

Might not be 100% possible, but you can put the right hand side in a method and annotate with `@Shared`. This would allow you to extract that piece of logic from each test.

For example:

```
myTest () {
    @Shared combinations = getCombinations()

    someTest() {

        ...
        where:
            [firstlibVersion, secondLibVersion] << combinations

    }

    def getCombinations() {
        [['0.1', '0.2'], ['0.2', '0.4']].combinations()
    }
```